# Access phpmyadmin from Cherrypy port 8080

Tags: web-server, php

I can access phpmyadmin from the host (raspberry pi) ip address (`http://192.168.1.109/phpmyadmin`) but i am running a server at port 8080 with cherrypy. I couldn't access

```
http://192.168.1.109:8080/phpmyadmin
```

I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 656, in respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 188, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/_cperror.py", line 386, in __call__
    raise self
NotFound: (404, "The path '/phpmyadmin' was not found.")
```

How should I configure my phpmyadmin or cherrypy?

Comment: So you have PhpMyAdmin running on top of CherryPy and you __can__ access it by http://192.168.1.109/phpmyadmin but not with http://192.168.1.109:8080/phpmyadmin? That means it runs on port 80 (which is taken as standard for http)

Comment: @M.Mimpen yes, my question is how can i configure so that my cherrypy web app can use the phpmyadmin?

Comment: You *can* access it via /phymyadmin but not via :8080/phpmyadmin? What's the problem then, you want to run it on 8080 instead of 80?

Comment: As said, I have cherrypy running at port 8080 that is why i'm asking if i should configure it to run phpmyadmin at port 8080? and how?

Comment: Put your files where CherryPy is listening then.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably tell your webserver on port 80 (mostlikely [Apache2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server)) to use [CherryPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CherryPy) as [WSGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface)
Probably like theis: http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/ModWSGI

I dont know what you want to do with it in combination with PHPMyAdmin, but if you need to have it all on one system, thats the way to go.
If you need it all to be on port 8080, you can tell Apache to [listen there](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html)